# How to apply Count on prefetched queryset in django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-prefetch-related

To demonstrate my use case, I've devised a similar but simpler setup as follows:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Routine(models.Model):
    owner =  models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='routine')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Routine | {self.owner}"


class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    routine = models.ForeignKey(Routine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='activities')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} | {'Active' if self.is_active else 'Expired'} | {self.routine.owner}"
```

```py
routines = Routine.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('activities', queryset=Activity.objects.filter(is_active=True))
)
```

The queryset above will retrieve all routines and their related active activities. However, some routines might not have any associated active activities, and in such cases, their activities will be empty.

```py
routines = Routine.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('activities', queryset=Activity.objects.filter(is_active=True))
).annotate(active_activity_count=Count("activities")).exclude(active_activity_count=0)
```

I updated the queryset to filter out routines with empty activities after prefetching active activities but this doesn't work. It seems like `Count` counts actual activities instead of prefetched activities.
Is there a way to make `Count` count prefetched activities?

Passing filter condition to `Count` makes it work:

```py
routines = Routine.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('activities', queryset=Activity.objects.filter(is_active=True))
).annotate(active_activity_count=Count("activities", filter=Q(activities__is_active=True))).exclude(active_activity_count=0)
```

But I don't want it because the condition in my original case is a bit complex so I don't want to repeat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the same effect with:

```
active_activities = Activity.objects.filter(is_active=True)
routines = Routine.objects.filter(activities__in=active_activities)
```

You can then chain `.prefetch_related('activities')` if you need them.

Comment: It gives FieldError "Cannot resolve keyword 'activity_for_count' into field. Choices are: activities, id, owner, owner_id"

Comment: Updated answer with another approach.

Comment: No error now but routines with empty activities are still present.

Comment: You're right - I can see where I went wrong too. Third time lucky - I think prefetch might be the wrong way to go.

Comment: Chaining .prefetch('activities') gives an attribute error but the following code snippet works:  

active_activities = Activity.objects.filter(is_active=True)  

routines = Routine.objects.filter(activities__in=active_activities).prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('activities', queryset=active_activities)
)

As I'm using ``active_activities`` at two places one for filtering routines and one for filtering activities I'm a bit concerned about the performance.

Comment: Typo on my part - use prefetch_related('activities').

Answer (score 0):

not tested  but maybe it works

```
routines = Routine.objects.prefetch_related('activities').filter(activities__is_active=True).annotate(activity_count=Count('activities'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefetch your related model and annotate the count while filtering as described in the aggregation [`documentation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations).

```py
routines = (
    Routine.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related("activities")
    .annotate(
        active_activity_count=Count(
            "activities", filter=Q(activities__is_active=True)
        )
    )
    .exclude(active_activity_count=0)
)
```